# django cant connect from outside (virtualbox + centos64 +python +django)

Tags: python, django

It's my 1st test but django doesn't work. django is the default setting.

How can i connect django web page? 
it installed virtualbox centos64

it cant connected from outside 
(same pc to vitualbox server)

(vsftpd is work to 192.168.0.8
sftp is right working .. it can connect from outside)

i updated the iptables as follows:

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8000 -j ACCEPT
```

Next, i ran these commands (but failed)

```
python manage.py runserver
python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000
python manage.py runserver 192.168.0.8:8000
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.1:8000
```

[virtualbox Network setting]
Bridged Adapter

but i cant test django page

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a misconfiguration in iptables. Try removing (or moving forward after "ACCEPTs")

```
-A INPUT -j REJECT -reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

In IPTABLES the order matters, if you put a reject that match before an ACCEPT, it always will take the reject.